# Removing deleted questions from the "Followed posts" list

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

My "Followed posts" list is littered with deleted questions, which I cannot remove off the list, as they've lost their "unfollow" option. How do I prune off these entries?

Comment: Undelete the question, unfollow, then delete again ;). But in all seriousness, it sounds like something SE needs to fix over all sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't via the Q&A page itself: see [How do I unfollow a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

As @MassimoOrtolano indicated in the comments, it is possible now via the [list of followed posts in your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following). However, you only see deleted posts there if you have 10k+ reputation, so this workaround doesn't work for everybody.

Comment: Mm... are you sure? If one goes to the "Following" tab in their own user profile, the unfollow button is available also for deleted questions. I've tested it on Academia and seems to work.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Ah yes. However, I think you can't do this on mobile browser unless you switch to a certain view. Maybe the OP is on mobile?

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano . You solved my problem: I don't go to my profile very often. The "working home" I use, clicking on my picture, gives a list with questions, and clicking on the pink-deleted question itself  does not have the unfollow button, even on a desktop... Nothing to do with mobile...

Comment: I field tested, successfully, @Massimo Ortolano's solution, which is mentioned in the link you provide, in a tentative comment. My sense says spelling out the > Profile > ... path instead of the Activity> ... path explicitly would make your fine answer plainly acceptable.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ah ok. Yeah if you go to that list on mobile the unfollow button is not on the list for each post. I thought you were looking at that list already, and when I first read your post I was on my phone :)

Comment: @BioPhysicist If you use the responsive view, the button is available as well also on mobile.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Right :) that is the "certain view" I was talking about earlier